# Lubuntu- chromium hangs after logout or suspend

Tags: lubuntu, chromium, lxde

My chromium hangs when I'm login after logout.

For example:

> 1. I'm closing chromium
> 2. I log out
> 3. I log in
> 4. I starting chromium
> 5. Chromium show his window and hangs on

Of course after computer restart everything is ok.

This is fresh system installation.I am using Lubuntu.

Did someone have similar problem?

I changed my chromium  theme from GTK to classic because I thought 
that this may be connected with GUI but that has changed nothing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge light-locker
```

Problem is that lightLocker don't like chromium.
This solution is only simple workaround. It will uninstall light-locker 
from your's system. In my case this solution is ok because maybe 
I lost possibility of lock screen but I no need to restart computer each time when lightlocker lock my screen or when I log out.